# optimize sql query rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

On posts index page I list all posts this way:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:comments).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <%= render @posts %>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<%= gravatar_for post.user, size:20 %>
<%= link_to "#{post.title}", post_path(post) %>
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> 
<%= post.comments.count %>
<%= post.category.name if post.category %>
```

35 posts per page

When I first load the page in dev env,
rack-mini-profiler shows this time: **1441.1 ms**

after a few reloads: **~700 ms**

**Can I somehow decrease this time and number of sql requests?**

Here're rmp images if it helps:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could decrease the number of sql queries by:

- including `user` as well as `comments`, since you seem to be using that when displaying the gravatar
- changing `post.comments.count` to `post.comments.size`

While size, count, length are synonymous for arrays, for active record relations or associations they are not the same:

- `length` loads the association (unless it is already loaded) and returns the length of the array
- `count` does a `select count(*) query` whether the association is loaded or not
- `size` uses `length` if the association is loaded and `count` if not.

In your case the comments association is loaded, but because you are using `count`, it's not actually used

Comment: 650 ms :) Is this all I can do for now? I'm also planning to use caching in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Further, you don't actually seem to be using the `comments` collection for anything other than printing the number of records. If that's indeed the case, use [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) (`4.1.2.3`) instead of querying for the comments (the number of comments will be available in the parent record `Post`).

Also consider a [client side alternative](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/105-not-use-time_ago_in_words) to `time_ago_in_words`. It will also help if you later decide to cache the entire section/page.

And finally retrieve only the fields you're going to use. In this case, I can imagine the `Post` contains a large amount of text for the content and it's not used anywhere (but still needs to be transmitted from the DB).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index on the reference column (comments in your case) might help.

```
add_index :posts, :comment_id
```