# Select multiple values from associated model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming I have this association

```
User have_many posts
Post belongs_to user

User   Post
----------------
id     id
name   title
       user_id
```

**How to list only post title and username with includes/joins ?**

(list of posts [title - username])

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).select('........')
```

don't offer this

```
@posts = Post.all.each {|p| p.user.username}
```

**__________________UP_____________________**

It worked for joining 2 tables.

What if I want to use it for more complex example?

check out my prev question [optimize sql query rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756532/optimize-sql-query-rails)

@Humza's answer partly worked.
it might be something like this

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user, :category).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
```

but It doesn't display posts that don't have category

I also need to display gravatar but I think I can just use user.email as usr_email and use gravatar_for (post.usr_email) but I'll have to customize gravatar helper for this.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:user).includes(:comments).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <%= render @posts %>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<%= gravatar_for post.user, size:20 %>
<%= link_to "#{post.title}", post_path(post) %>
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> 
<%= post.comments.count %>
<%= post.category.name if post.category %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post.joins(:user, :category)
```

> but It doesn't display posts that don't have category

That's because `joins` uses `INNER JOIN` to join the tables together. If you want to everything from `Post` even though the particular record doesn't have its counterpart in the other table, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`. Unfortunately `ActiveRecord` doesn't have a nice way of generating it and you will need to do that manually:

```
Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ON categories.post_id = posts.id")...
```

See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

Comment: You kicked me in the right direction) Now I have this: Post.joins(:user).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.category_id").select("posts.id as id, posts.title AS title, posts.created_at AS created_at, categories.name as cat_n, users.email AS user_em").paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck).

```
Post.joins(:user).pluck(:title, :name)
```

Note that it works in this case because there's no ambiguity regarding the `name` column, you might want to specify the table explicitly (`pluck(:title, "users.name")`).

Comment: It works but I got an error when render @posts  ....is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path. Updated question.

Comment: Yeah, `pluck` always returns a plain Ruby array.

Answer (score 3):

`includes` is used in case of eager-loading. You need `joins` in this case.

```
posts = Post.joins(:user).select("posts.title AS title, users.name AS username")
```

You can access the values then in the following way:

```
post = posts.first
post.title # will give the title of the post
post.username # will give the name of the user that this post belongs to
```

If you can `pluck` multiple columns, then the following might be more useful to you:

```
posts = Post.joins(:user).pluck("posts.title", "users.name")
```

The result will be a 2D array, with each element being an array of the form `[post_title, post_username]`

Comment: It kind of worked for me but what if I have a more complex association. Updated my question. Can you also suggest any articles about joins. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can call array methods on a scope so:

```
Post.includes(:user).map { |p| [p.title, p.user.name] }
```

will get the posts with included user and map each post to a tuple of the post title and the user name.

That may not entirely answer your question as I think you might want to restrict the results of the query to just the required fields in which case, I *think* you can add a `.select('title', 'users.name')` to the query. (Not in a position to test at the moment)